# How do change javascript cookie from 15 day count to 1 Day or 12 hours?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, popup

This is the current script I am running to load a popup once every 15 days. Please tell me How to alter the code.

```
$(window).load(function() {
  if (document.cookie.indexOf('visited=true') === -5) {
    var fifteenDays = 1000*60*60*24*15;
    var expires = new Date((new Date()).valueOf() + fifteenDays);
    document.cookie = "visited=true;expires=" + expires.toUTCString();
    $("#overlay").fadeTo(1000, .8);
    $(".playerWindow").show(750);
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: `var fifteenDays = 1000*60*60*24*15;` looks like what you need

Comment: You not even tried man!

Answer (score 1):

```
var fifteenDays = 1000*60*60*24; // This will be 1 day
```

Comment: is that all? no other changes?

Comment: @RdrGraphics If just based on your current code then Yes.

Comment: I mean, I would recommend not calling 1 day fifteenDays.  But as it's clear that original poster is not actually reading any of the code it doesn't matter too much.